# How to use couchbase to send requests to my own api

Tags: android, couchbase-lite

I have a list of objects which saves some users data. I saved these objects in a databse using couchbase lite in the documents. I could not understand how the sync gateway and couchbase server will send(sync) these saved user data to my server using the api of send user data in my app. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Data from Couchbase Lite will be synced to Sync Gateway via replication protocol (you configure the replicator on your couchbase lite to talk to Sync Gateway) and the Sync Gateway persists data in the Couchbase Server.
You are responsible for pulling data from Couchbase Server into your server. There are [connectors](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.1/connectors/intro.html) available for integrations.

Comment: Ok I am confused here regarding the need of connectors. My doubt is How the couchbase server will call the exact api from my side of backend. How will my backend server integrate with the couchbase server?

Comment: A typical implementation is CBL <-> SG <-> CBS <-> Backend app.  That is, your backend application uses Couchbase Server as the backing database, knowing that the data is synced from the mobile app via Sync Gateway.  If you want to have a REST api automatically called, look at either web hooks in Sync Gateway or the Eventing Service in Couchbase Server.